# Creating a bootable Ubuntu Server flash drive in OS X

Tags: macos, ubuntu, usb, boot, iso-image

I wish to create a bootable Ubuntu Server flash drive. I downloaded the ISO, but all instructions I find online don't work because in this version of OS X (Lion) the [ISO cannot be mounted because it is a hybrid ISO](https://askubuntu.com/questions/153833/why-cant-i-mount-the-ubuntu-12-04-installer-isos-in-mac-os-x). This means I can't create a bootable flash drive using either command line or disk utility. How can I create a bootable flash drive using Mac OS X.

Answer (score 0):

On Ubuntu's Website

http://www.ubuntu.com/download/help/create-a-usb-stick-on-mac-osx

Comment: That doesn't work. As I stated, the os isn't able to mount the ISO due to a reuse of the same UUID across multiple partitions of the same drive. I can't use the method described on the linked website because that involves the os mounting the ISO, which it cannot.

Comment: The link refers to an open-source utility called [Etcher](https://etcher.io/) which makes burning an iso file to a flash drive very easy. With this I have successfully created a modern Ubuntu boot "stick" on my Macbook.